# What is the best way to both drop columns and insert column names using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a csv with a few dozen columns that are all unnamed by default and about half of which need to be removed. I've figured out how to name the columns upon import. Example:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('ColumnNameTest.csv', names=['ID', 'Name', 'Flavor'])
```

And I *think* I figured out how to drop columns:

```
df.drop('Flavor', axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

But what is the most efficient way to drop about a dozen columns and insert the column names?
Do I have to name all the columns first, then just drop them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drop alot of columns and keep some, you can use iloc to select a subset of columns:

```
df.iloc[:,[3,5,9,10]]
#then name all columns that left
df.columns=['col3','col5','col9','col10']
```

Or keep a range of columns:

```
df.iloc[:,3:9]
```

Comment: Thank you. When it comes to naming columns, do I have to name them as soon as I bring in the CSV or can it be accomplished after I've isolated the columns I need?

Comment: It's better to name them after cause this way you will not do something unuseful...

Comment: Thank you. I'm still struggling to figure out how to name columns after the initial read_csv. Every time I've tried to rename the columns, it ends up overwriting the first row...

Comment: use `pd.read_csv(filepath,columns=[columns name])` when you want to do it while reading. `df.columns=[columns name]` when you want to do it afterward